# How to put <ul> around image in css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, as the title says, I want to put `<ul>` around an image. The `ul` got 4 `<li>`, and I want to put 2 `<li>` on the left side of the image, and 2 `<li>` on the right side:

```
<ONE>-----<TWO>-----(imageLOGO.png)-----<THREE>-----<FOUR>
```

Here is how it looks at the moment: [image]

As you can see the 4 `<li>` are at the top left corner of the site. They are put on the blue line from the same `<div>` - `#line` . I tried with padding, but it looks really bad, and it is hard to control once the page is minimized or resized in any way.

Here is the html file:

```
<body>
    <div id="line">
        <div class="line-menu">
            <ul class="menu-buttons">
                <li>ONE</li>
                <li>TWO</li>
                <li>TREE</li>
                <li>FOUR</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="top">
            <div id="logo">
                <img src="images/chelsea-logo.png">
            </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

And the css file:

```
body {

    background: url('../images/background.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0;  
}

#top{

    width: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 150px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#top img {

    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#top img:hover {

    width: 158px;
    height: 158px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

#line {

    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    background: #423BD9;
}

.line-menu {

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.line-menu ul {

display: inline-block;
padding: 5px;
margin: 25px;

}

.line-menu li {

padding: 0 89px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

I'll provide more information if needed. Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Can the HTML mark-up be modified or is this predetermined by other requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it.

You have the right idea by using absolute positioning to place the logo over the link panel.

I specified a width for the `li` elements and then applied `text-align: center` on the parent `ul` to keep then centered.

To open up space for the logo, I added a right-margin of 200px between the 2nd and 3rd `li` elements, using the `nth-child` selector.

You can adjust margins on various elements to control the spacing between and above the `li` elements.

Note, for smaller screena, you may need to use media queries and make adjustments to the margins and so on.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#top {
  border: 1px dotted black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#top img {
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
#top img:hover {
  width: 158px;
  height: 158px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
#line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  background: #423BD9;
}
.line-menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.line-menu ul {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.line-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
.line-menu li:nth-child(2) {
  margin-right: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="line">
  <div class="line-menu">
    <ul class="menu-buttons">
      <li>ONE</li>
      <li>TWO</li>
      <li>THREE</li>
      <li>FOUR</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="top">
  <div id="logo">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much about the suggestion. It worked pretty good. I didn't know about this `nth-child` selector, but I'm still pretty new to web developing so I learn something new every day.

Answer (score 0):

Add image after one and two.  And .list-menu li  float:left;  display:block;